# How can I get the input fields, to sit side by side with the textarea, instead of them overlapping?

Tags: html, css

```css
/*******************************************************************************/
/* Section 4: Contact Area */

#section4{
 width:1903px;
}

#contact_area{
 background-color:red;
 /* max-width:750px; */
 padding-top:80px;
 padding-bottom:60px;
 width:1903px;
}

.contact_container{
 background-color:orange;
 margin:0px 576.500px; /* centers the entire column in the center of the contact area section */
 padding:0px 15px; /* puts padding around the left/right sides of the container */
 max-width:750px;
}

#contact_row_1A{
 display:table; /* changes the display property of the row to act as a table */
}

#contact_column_1{
 float:left;
}

.contact_content_1A{
 text-align:center; /* centers the header and the text */
}

#contact_row_1B{
 display:table;
}

#contact_column_2{
 float:left;
 padding-left:15px;
 padding-right:15px;
 width:690px; /* makes the width of the column 690px */
}

/* controls the text above the input fields */
#contact_text{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the text */
 border-radius:5px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 font-size:18px; /* changes the size of the text to 18px */
 /* margin-bottom:20px; */
 padding:15px 0px;
}

#contact_row_2A{
 display:table; /* puts both rows into 1 table */
 width:750px; /* controls the size of the row */
}

/* controls the column containing the input fields */
#contact_column_form_left{
 float:left; /* puts the 3 input fields on the left */
 padding-left:0px; /* makes the column w/ the input fields align with the text above them */ /* when set to 0, the columns stay side by side */
 /* padding-right:15px; */
 width:50%;
}

#contact_column_form_right{
 float:left; /* puts the 3 input fields on the left */
 padding-right:0px; /* makes the column w/ the input fields align with the text above them */ /* when set to 0, the columns stay side by side */
 width:50%;
}

.form_control{
 /* display:block; */
 margin-bottom:15px; /* adds margins to the bottoms of the input fields to space then out */
 /* width:100%; */
}

#name_input{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the input field */
 border:none; /* removes the default border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%; /* the width of the input field is the full length of the column it in */
}

#email_input{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the input field */
 border:none; /* removes the border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%; /* the width of the input field is the full length of the column it in */
}

#subject_input{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the input field */
 border:none; /* removes the border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%; /* the width of the input field is the full length of the column it in */
}

/* controls the textarea element */
textarea.form_control{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4);
 border:none; /* removes the border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 /* flex-direction:column; */
 height:auto;
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%;
}

/* controls the contact form's button */
#contact_btn{
 background:#262628; /* colors the button */
 border:1px solid #ccc; /* changes the border around the button */
 border-radius:10px; /* rounds the default border around the button */
 color:#fff; /* colors the text of the button */
 /* display:inline-block;*/
 font-size:18px; /* changes the size of the font of the button */
 /* margin-top:20px; /* adds a margin between the textarea and the button */
 padding:10px 30px; /* adds padding between the button's text and its border */
}

.form_control{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="section4">

            <!-- section -->
      <section id="contact_area">

       <!-- container -->
       <div class="contact_container">

        <!-- row 1 -->
        <div id="contact_row_1A">
         
                        <!-- column -->
                        <div class="contact_column_1">

                            <!-- column -->
                           <div class="contact_content_1A">

                                <h1>Contact Form</h1>

                                <!-- row 2 -->
                                <div id="contact_row_1B">

                                    <!-- column -->
                                    <div id="contact_column_2">
                                        <p id="contact_text">Nunc diam leo, fringilla vulputate elit lobortis, consectetur vestibulum quam. Sed id
                                        <br>
                                        felis ligula. In euismod libero at magna dapibus, in rutrum velit lacinia.
                                        <br>
                                        Etiam a mi quis arcu varius condimentum.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
        </div>

                    <!-- row 2 -->
                    <div id="contact_row_2A">
                        
                        <!-- column -->
                        <div id="contact_column_3">

                            <!-- form -->
                            <form class="contact_form" action="#" method="post">

                                <!-- column -->
                                <div id="contact_column_form_left">

                                    <!-- form group -->
                                    <div class="form_group">
                                        
                                        <!-- input field 1 -->
                                        <input class="form_control" id="name_input" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="name">

                                        <!-- input field 2 -->
                                        <input class="form_control" id="email_input" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">

                                        <!-- input field 3 -->
                                        <input class="form_control" id="subject_input" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="name">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- column -->
                                <div id="contact_column_form_right">

                                    <!-- form group -->
                                    <div class="form_group">

                                        <!-- textarea -->
                                        <textarea class="form_control" id="comment" name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea>
                                        <button id="contact_btn" type="submit">Send</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
       </div>
      </section>
     </div>
```

Im building this practice website.

I have figured out most of the problems I have had, but im stuck on the current issue.

In the Contact section of the site, I want a group of input fields to sit right next to the textarea. But they keep overlapping.`

What should I do to stop them from overlapping, and to sit next to each other within the same div?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, welcome back to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to properly ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to better assist you, could you provide us with the code you're working with ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your CSS styles, to make the components' width and height also include the padding and border, not just the contents...

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/*******************************************************************************/
/* Section 4: Contact Area */

#section4{
 width:1903px;
}

#contact_area{
 background-color:red;
 /* max-width:750px; */
 padding-top:80px;
 padding-bottom:60px;
 width:1903px;
}

.contact_container{
 background-color:orange;
 margin:0px 576.500px; /* centers the entire column in the center of the contact area section */
 padding:0px 15px; /* puts padding around the left/right sides of the container */
 max-width:750px;
}

#contact_row_1A{
 display:table; /* changes the display property of the row to act as a table */
}

#contact_column_1{
 float:left;
}

.contact_content_1A{
 text-align:center; /* centers the header and the text */
}

#contact_row_1B{
 display:table;
}

#contact_column_2{
 float:left;
 padding-left:15px;
 padding-right:15px;
 width:690px; /* makes the width of the column 690px */
}

/* controls the text above the input fields */
#contact_text{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the text */
 border-radius:5px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 font-size:18px; /* changes the size of the text to 18px */
 /* margin-bottom:20px; */
 padding:15px 0px;
}

#contact_row_2A{
 display:table; /* puts both rows into 1 table */
 width:750px; /* controls the size of the row */
}

/* controls the column containing the input fields */
#contact_column_form_left{
 float:left; /* puts the 3 input fields on the left */
 padding-left:0px; /* makes the column w/ the input fields align with the text above them */ /* when set to 0, the columns stay side by side */
 /* padding-right:15px; */
 width:50%;
}

#contact_column_form_right{
 float:left; /* puts the 3 input fields on the left */
 padding-right:0px; /* makes the column w/ the input fields align with the text above them */ /* when set to 0, the columns stay side by side */
 width:50%;
}

.form_control{
 /* display:block; */
 margin-bottom:15px; /* adds margins to the bottoms of the input fields to space then out */
 /* width:100%; */
}

#name_input{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the input field */
 border:none; /* removes the default border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%; /* the width of the input field is the full length of the column it in */
}

#email_input{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the input field */
 border:none; /* removes the border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%; /* the width of the input field is the full length of the column it in */
}

#subject_input{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4); /* adds a transparent background color behind the input field */
 border:none; /* removes the border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%; /* the width of the input field is the full length of the column it in */
}

/* controls the textarea element */
textarea.form_control{
 background-color:rgba(242,242,242,0.4);
 border:none; /* removes the border around the input field */
 border-radius:4px; /* rounds the borders around the input fields */
 /* flex-direction:column; */
 height:auto;
 padding:6px 12px; /* adds padding inside the input field */
 width:100%;
}

/* controls the contact form's button */
#contact_btn{
 background:#262628; /* colors the button */
 border:1px solid #ccc; /* changes the border around the button */
 border-radius:10px; /* rounds the default border around the button */
 color:#fff; /* colors the text of the button */
 /* display:inline-block;*/
 font-size:18px; /* changes the size of the font of the button */
 /* margin-top:20px; /* adds a margin between the textarea and the button */
 padding:10px 30px; /* adds padding between the button's text and its border */
}

.form_control{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="section4">

            <!-- section -->
      <section id="contact_area">

       <!-- container -->
       <div class="contact_container">

        <!-- row 1 -->
        <div id="contact_row_1A">
         
                        <!-- column -->
                        <div class="contact_column_1">

                            <!-- column -->
                           <div class="contact_content_1A">

                                <h1>Contact Form</h1>

                                <!-- row 2 -->
                                <div id="contact_row_1B">

                                    <!-- column -->
                                    <div id="contact_column_2">
                                        <p id="contact_text">Nunc diam leo, fringilla vulputate elit lobortis, consectetur vestibulum quam. Sed id
                                        <br>
                                        felis ligula. In euismod libero at magna dapibus, in rutrum velit lacinia.
                                        <br>
                                        Etiam a mi quis arcu varius condimentum.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
        </div>

                    <!-- row 2 -->
                    <div id="contact_row_2A">
                        
                        <!-- column -->
                        <div id="contact_column_3">

                            <!-- form -->
                            <form class="contact_form" action="#" method="post">

                                <!-- column -->
                                <div id="contact_column_form_left">

                                    <!-- form group -->
                                    <div class="form_group">
                                        
                                        <!-- input field 1 -->
                                        <input class="form_control" id="name_input" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="name">

                                        <!-- input field 2 -->
                                        <input class="form_control" id="email_input" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">

                                        <!-- input field 3 -->
                                        <input class="form_control" id="subject_input" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="name">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- column -->
                                <div id="contact_column_form_right">

                                    <!-- form group -->
                                    <div class="form_group">

                                        <!-- textarea -->
                                        <textarea class="form_control" id="comment" name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea>
                                        <button id="contact_btn" type="submit">Send</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
       </div>
      </section>
     </div>
```